# Connecting to a PSSession wit start-job

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I'm trying to create a function that login into remote machines using PSSEssion.
The idea is that those sessions will be running in the background well the script does other things.

The issue is when I use `Get-Job`, I can see the jobs were completed:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location     
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------    
2      Job2            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost      
4      Job4            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost
```

When I use `Receive-Job -Id 2 -Keep`,  I can also see the result to:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0        tmp_jeenmyes.e5c                    {Search-AdminAuditLog,
```

The problem is when I use `Get-PSSession` it is empty. it does not show the new sessions.  I can't use the new commands either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your time.

```
function Sessions {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, 
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        $AdminAccount
    )

    begin {
        # Delete 'Broken' Sessions
        $PSSession = Get-PSSession
        foreach ($Session in $PSSession) {
            IF ($Session.State -eq 'Broken') {
                Remove-PSSession -id $Session.id
            }
        }
        # SeesionOption for a longer session
        $SeesionOptions = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout $(60000 * 60) `
            -OpenTimeout $(60000 * 60) -OperationTimeout $(60000 * 60)
    }

    process {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            $CloudSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
                -ConnectionUri "https://pod51043psh.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?PSVersion=5.0.9814.0" `
                -Credential $args[0] -Authentication Basic -SessionOption $args[1] 
            Import-PSSession $CloudSession
        } -ArgumentList $LocalCred, $SeesionOptions 

        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            $OnPremisesSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
                -ConnectionUri http://wki-exch01.domain.com/powershell/ `
                -Credential $args[0] -Authentication Kerberos -SessionOption $args[1] 

            Import-PSSession $OnPremisesSession
        } -ArgumentList $LocalCred, $SeesionOptions
    }
    end {
    }
}

Sessions -AdminAccount $Localcred
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you overall goal? Are you trying to use Powershell Implicit remoting so you can use some remote functions locally?

If so the general syntax for your script will be:

```
#start of script
Param(
    $AdminAccount
)
$DCSession = New-PSSession -Computername DC1 -Credential $AdminAccount
Invoke-Command -Session $DCSession -ScriptBlock {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession -Session $DCSession -Module ActiveDirectory

#continue with script commands here using the imported functions/module as if they were local
```

Comment: it takes more than 3 minutes to connect to all the pssession that we have. The idea is to have the sessions connecting in the background. so I can work on other things well that is happening.

Comment: i think when you run a job, it is running the command in another powershell instance.  So you can't access variables ,sessions from that instance.  Maybe go to Starbucks while the sessions are being established :).